# Calculate value based on condition in other column in Excel

Tags: excel

I want to calculate the average of all row in column A where column B has the value 'same'

```
A   |  B
-----------
o.1 | same
0.2 | different
0.2 | same
```

The usual average for the whole data set looks like this:

```
=AVERAGE(Table8[A])
```

But I want something like this:

```
=AVERAGE(Table8[A] WHERE Table8[B] = 'same')
```

From the table above I need to get 0.15 as average.

**EDIT**: Additionally STDEV, QUARTILE and other functions should be usable as well

Comment: Excel has a great little function called AVERAGEIF().  A quick search on google will give you plenty of examples.

Comment: Okay sounds good. Is the same thing available for STDEV, QUARTILE and so on?

Comment: No, You will need to use an array formula for those.  STDEV(IF(Table8[B] = "same",Table8[A])) and use Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode to force an array.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A100)*(B1:B100="same"))/COUNTIF(B1:B100,"same")
```

change the ***100*** to suit your needs.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I just updated my question. Should be appliable to more functions than average